Ubuntu 22.04 dies all of a sudden after some time, yet the PC is still running
I've recently started running into a strange issue with Ubuntu 22.04 (x64), can't quite understand what's going on. It's a (kinda) old computer that's a temporary solution for Discord bot hosting, which means it runs 24/7. It appears that after 16-20 hours of hosting the bots, Ubuntu suddenly dies, even though the PC doesn't stop running. As "dies", I mean that nothing gets outputted to the screen, any actions except for the power button press are completely unresponsive, and the keyboard/mouse lights are dead, too. It definitely is not stuck being unresponsive, otherwise it'd respond to REISUB or something.
After a restart the system successfully booted, and I thought it was a short power outage that caused this. The problem reappeared today. I checked /var/log/syslog. There are no crashes / fatals / kernel panics, but it seems like there were no logs after 2:27 AM (which might be the time of death for my Ubuntu today). After that, I thought that BIOS diagnostics might show me that something was wrong. Unfortunately, nothing.
The PC has a dual-core Intel Pentium E6800 (3.33 GHz) with 4GB of DDR3 RAM, an Nvidia GT230, and 2 HDDs (with the system sitting on the 512GB one).
Typically the CPU runs at 40°C, around 30%. RAM usage doesn't go above 2.8GB. Googled this, and sadly it seems like I'm the only one with this issue who decided to post (or am I?).
Does anyone have any idea what's happening with my PC? Should I simply shut it down and wait till the factory-new one is ready? Or is it a system/hardware failure that is possible to resolve? Any help is appreciated!
EDIT: The same happened again, seems like it's a hardware issue and is not an Ubuntu bug. Based on other diagnostics, the PC gets stuck in an error loop whenever this issue occurs. I'll see what else I can find out.

On an older PC, try reverting to an older Ubuntu version, e.g., 20.04 LTS. No need to install, just run from USB for a few days to test if that fixes the issue.

@John Good idea, thanks for pointing that out.

Is it really dead, and not just the display & keyboard? No ping/ssh? Since you mention that syslog has no entries that does look like it's really died or frozen suddenly, but it's worth testing the "magic" SysRq keys (sometimes they're not even all enabled, see /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq ) when not frozen to get the keys right (don't work with right alt on a newer kernel for me for some reason). Or try upgrading/downgrading the kernel too, before the whole Ubuntu version.

@DrMoishePippik Will definitely try that. I think I might even install 20.04 LTS if it turns out to work properly and if Ubuntu 22.04 continues to act like this, thank you.

@Xen2050 I have a couple of clients that connect to the things hosted on this Ubuntu, it errors out because the other side doesn't have anything running during the dead state. Seems like it actually is dead. Good idea with the SysRq keys, by the way, I'll try to use those the next time my Ubuntu dies like that (if it ever does this again). Appreciate the advice!

@John Maybe, I'll see what happens after an update (if anything happens at all), thank you.
